# How can I specify keystore and trust store in application.yaml for ssl client?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, yaml

I have a spring boot application that calls an ssl enabled rest service that requires mutual ssl authentication. I need to specify a key store and trust store to make the call in this client application.

When I specify the keystore and trust store info (paths, types and passwords of both key and trust store jks files) inside the Java code like the following, the call works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/to/tmnt-truststore");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/path/to/donatello.p12");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "donatellopass");
```

But how do I specify that in application.yaml.

I tried with the following pattern specifyint keystore, truststore, key and trust store types and passwords, exactly all the info I specified using the System.setProperty.

```
javax:
    net:
        ssl:
            trust-store: /path/to/tmnt-truststore
```

But doesn't work.
I get error with message

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Tried specifying both patterns `trust-store` and `trustStore` for both keystore and trust store.

This client app also exposes a rest endpoint and that info is specified in the same yaml file as

```
server:
    context-path: /my-context
    port: 8200
spring:
    application:
        name: mhapp
```

That info seems to be getting picked up by the applicaiton. But not the javax.net.ssl.keyStore, etc.

How do I specify that in the `application.yaml` and do I need to do something else, like add any annotation, to load that info?

Answer (score 1):

please try like below in application.property file first if its works fine you can put it in an yaml file,

```
server.ssl.key-alias=selfsigned
server.ssl.key-password=test123
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
```

If not you can put all the values in a property file and you can create a configuration file like below this will give the rest template to call external service,

```
@Configuration
public class SslConfiguration {
    @Value("${http.client.ssl.trust-store}")
    private Resource keyStore;
    @Value("${http.client.ssl.trust-store-password}")
    private String keyStorePassword;

    @Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception {
        SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
                .loadTrustMaterial(
                        keyStore.getURL(),
                        keyStorePassword.toCharArray()
                ).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = 
                new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = 
                new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
        return new RestTemplate(factory);
    }
}
```